# TypeError: test_admin_login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm writing test cases for my Django-based rest APIs. The problem is in the method of testcase class. I want to use ***test_admin_login*** method in the ***setuptestdata*** method. And I'm unable to do that. I'm getting error that I mentioned in the title.

```
class MyTests(TestCase):
    allow_database_queries: True
    client = APIClient()

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # client = APIClient()
        # AUTHENTICATION 
        # response = cls.client.post(reverse('auth'),data={"username":"admin","password":"ppoopp00"},format='json')
        value = cls.test_admin_login()
        print(value)
        cls.auth_token = cls.test_admin_login(cls)

        # CREATE PROJECT
        response = cls.client.post(
            reverse('projects:project_create'),
            data={"platform_subscriber_entity":"NucoinTest"},
            format='json', 
            HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="JWT "+cls.auth_token
            
        )
        cls.project_key  = response.data["platform_subscriber_id"]


    def test_admin_login(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new account object.
        """
        url = reverse('auth')
        response = self.client.post(url,data={"username":"admin","password":"testpass"},format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 2)
        return response.data["access"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if any function needs the `self` this means you need to create an instance of it first to use it and you use `cls` not an instance so all you need is to create an instance

```py
cls().test_admin_login(cls)
```